# IsChecked property is binded to an observable collection

Tags: wpf

I am using the DataGrid of WPF. In this Grid first column is checkbox.Remaining columns are exported from an excel.So the Itemsource is the default view of that datatable.My problem is IsChecked property is binded to an observable collection.i couldn't save the checked state of checkbox column.Please find the code below.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grdSelect" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  MinWidth="186" CanUserSortColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Column="1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}" CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
                  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                  MaxHeight="300" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionChanged="DataGridSelectionChangedEventHandler">
                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF003878" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFF0F0F1" />
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.Resources>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="checkboxtemplate">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox x:Name="checkData" IsChecked="{Binding DataChecked, 
                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                      Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                              Unchecked="DataRowCheckedUncheckedEventHandler"
                                      Checked="DataRowCheckedUncheckedEventHandler"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataPath))
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                //Dynamic File Using Uploader...........
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelBook =
                    excelApp.Workbooks.Open(dataPath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelSheet =
                    (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1); ;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelRange = excelSheet.UsedRange;

            string strCellData = "";
            double douCellData;
            int rowCnt = 0;
            int colCnt = 0;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            for (colCnt = 1; colCnt <= excelRange.Columns.Count; colCnt++)
            {
                string strColumn = "";
                strColumn = (string)(excelRange.Cells[1, colCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2;
                dt.Columns.Add(strColumn, typeof(string));
            }

            for (rowCnt = 2; rowCnt <= excelRange.Rows.Count; rowCnt++)
            {
                string strData = "";
                for (colCnt = 1; colCnt <= excelRange.Columns.Count; colCnt++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        strCellData = (string)(excelRange.Cells[rowCnt, colCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2;
                        if (strCellData != null)
                        {
                            strData += strCellData + "|";
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        douCellData = (excelRange.Cells[rowCnt, colCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2;
                        strData += douCellData.ToString() + "|";
                    }
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strData))
                {
                    strData = strData.Remove(strData.Length - 1, 1);
                    dt.Rows.Add(strData.Split('|'));
                }
            }

            grdSelect.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;                
            //grdSelect.Loaded += SetMinWidths;
            //grdSelect.Width = excelRange.Rows.Count * 27;

            excelBook.Close(true, null, null);
            excelApp.Quit();
        }
```

Comment: Please post codes of your Model and ViewModel classes also. Experts may need to look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand from your question you have two datasources ObservableCollection for checked status and DataTable for showing data imported from Excel.

But since DataGrid has only one property DataContext you need to merge this two datasource into one and then bind this new datasource.

One easy option I see is that you can add one more boolean column to your DataTable and then bind DataTable. This way you can get checked status and also able to display excel data.